# How to connect parts of mechanism and make them relative to each other?

Tags: units

I have number of objects and I want to make them relative to each other. When I change location of one part other parts should either rotate or change their location also.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly what you want, parent A to B. Put the origin of A at the rotation axis (here, at the tip of the cone):

[image]

If moving an object makes another one rotate, you can give a *Transformation* constraint to the rotating object.